# Invalid object type `GtkGrid' using Glade + Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk

I am trying to make a simple gui for a log parser application Im currently writting and Im having slight trouble using glade to design the whole thing. The script is in python 2.7.3, GTK is installed on the machine.

```
<object class="GtkGrid" id="grid1">
```

This is probably causing the trouble, but I am unable to find out why. Parent is a Window. I want to use the grid for relative placement after resizing the window. If I use "layout" or "fixed" elements instead of the grid, everything works, but the placement of each element would be more troublesome than while using a grid.

Comment: GTK and Glade version?  A mismatch could be the reason for the error.

Comment: Glade version 3.14.2 and GTK tested both GTK2x and 3x versions. Both exhibit the same error.

Comment: A little code (especially imports and use of the Gtk builder API) would help. @liberforce was able to give a good hint but no remedy.

Comment: Yup, liberforce's advice was actually right on spot. And yours as well after all. I found out, that the installation of GTK3 on the machine seemed succesfull, but really wasnt. Much of GTK3 packages were simply not there. Thanks for your effort, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GtkGrid](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html) is available since GTK 3, so make sure your application uses GTK 3 (using [PyGObject](http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject)), and not GTK 2 (using PyGTK).

Here's the official [Python GTK+ 3 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Oh thats the real problem then! Thanks a bunch for this. I have changed GtkGrid to Table and it works nicely. Problem was I have to develop on a windows server machine and GTK3 installation wasnt "properly done" even it seemed so.

Thanks again!